# Joomla member user groups

Tags: joomla, usergroups

I want to be able to create a members area in Joomla which would be split into 3 groups. People from each group would only be able to see content for their group, profiles for their group and also only participate in discussion forums for their group. Ideally, members would be able to choose what group they wanted to join when they first registered.

Does anyone know what the best solution, or combination of solutions, would be able to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like JUGA http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/2587

Comment: Hi Jeepstone, Thank you for your answer. I have downloaded JUGA and will give it a try. I think it covers everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

You must get Joomla!'s latest major release, 1.6, to achieve user groups. In fact, it was just released Monday January 10th, 2011.

All versions prior to 1.6 can not achieve user groups without an extension.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have already built quite an extensive site using 1.5 and it is a bit late to re-build it now. Do you know of an extension I could use to achieve user groups? Thanks

Comment: I have never used such an extension and I wouldn't know where to direct you on the topic. What I have done in the past is used PHPBB for my forum and used Joomla! for the main part of the site. I understand though that this is only a solution for a forum and not for content such as articles and in depth user profiles. Sorry I couldn't help you more on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use [K2](http://getk2.org). It's a content construction kit for Joomla and features users groups... You can define what each group see and more than that (editing, commenting, adding galleries, videos ... more)

It's open source and free... One of the most popular extensions in Joomla at the moment and it can import your Joomla content.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thank you very much for your response. I hadn't considered K2 as I didn't think it could help me but that sounds very interesting. I have already paid for JUGA now so will try that out first, but will certainly look into K2. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Pleasure is mine :) I've never used JUGA so if you could spend some time and report your impression and weather you're satisfied or not with JUGA after you have some time to test it, I will really appreciate that... Keep up the informative postings :)